# SQL алгоритм выполения

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос вида

```
with myselect as (select * 
                  from table1 
                  where column1 = 1)
select * 
from table2 
where column21  in (select column11 
                    from myselect) 
  and  column22  in (select column12 
                     from myselect);
```

Это тоже самое что

```
select * 
from table2 
where column21  in (select column11 
                    from table1 
                    where column1 = 1) 
  and  column22  in (select column12 
                     from table1 
                    where column1 = 1);
```

Во втором случае, насколько я понимаю, сначала выполнится один встроенный селект с таблицы column11, потом другой с той же таблицы и после верхний запрос с table2.

Как будет работать запрос в первом случае. Он сначала выберет с table1, потом будет в подзапросах выбирать с уже выбранного набора или же это синтетический сахар и все-равно будет выбирать каждый раз в подзапросах с table1? Может кто подскажет по алгоритму выполнения?

Comment: Что гадать-то? запросите планы выполнения запросов - там всё рассказано.

Comment: так я и спросил здесь, чтобы не гадать. План запроса нужно правильно прочитать еще